The Live Server plugin installation in VSCode hangs in WSL2
I'm using VSCode in WSL Ubuntu 24.04. The host is Windows 11.
Installing the Live Server plugin in WSL just hangs. In Windows 11 there were no problems.
Did anybody experience this and knows what could be the problem?

I guess this is some kind of a hiccup that goes away by itself.
When I've disconnected from WSL and connected again, the plugin appeared in the "WSL:UBUNTU" plugin list.
